# How Can I Get percentile(%) Columns Using TSQL Code

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have 2 Columns in a table...
which are :

```
HCode           No_of contacts
AA1             78
AA2             10 
AA3             09
AA4             14
AA5             10 
AA1             21
```

I have written the following code:

```
select HCode, Sum(No_of contacts) as NoOFContacts
from #T
Group by  HCode 
order by  HCode
```

Using the above code, how can I populate a Percentage column based on max([No_of contacts])?

Comment: Even though this question has an accepted answer I'm curious as to what the expected output would be, because the output from the accepted answer doesn't really make any sense to me (but maybe I'm just being stupid).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Analytical functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms189461.aspx) to get the max number of contracts, without having to do a separate subuery to get this:

```
CREATE TABLE #T (HCode VARCHAR(3), No_of_contacts INT);

INSERT #T (HCode, No_of_contacts)
VALUES ('AA1', 78), ('AA2', 10), ('AA3', 09), 
        ('AA4', 14), ('AA5', 10), ('AA1', 21);

SELECT  HCode,
        No_of_contacts,
        PercentOfContracts = 100.0 * No_of_contacts / MAX(No_of_contacts) OVER()
FROM    (   SELECT  HCode,
                    No_of_contacts = SUM(No_of_contacts)
            FROM    #T
            GROUP BY Hcode
        ) AS t;
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is what you want?

```
select 
    HCode, 
    Sum([No_of contacts]) as NoOFContacts, 
    Sum([No_of contacts])*100/(select Sum([No_of contacts]) from #t) as Percentage
from #t
Group by HCode 
order by HCode
```

This would render the following result:

```
HCode      NoOFContacts Percentage
---------- ------------ -----------
AA1        99           69
AA2        10           7
AA3        9            6
AA4        14           9
AA5        10           7

(5 row(s) affected)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with a nested sql statement

```
select Hcode, (NumberAcc/SumAcc)*100 as Percentage, Sumacc
from
(select Hcode, Sum(no_Of contacts) as SumAcc, no_OfContacts as NumberAcc
from #t
group by HCode, no_OfContacts) as T
```

Comment: Hi Friends Sorry i neeed to get Percentage based on Max(No_of_Contacts)!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!                                     select 
    HCode, 
    Sum([No_of contacts]) as NoOFContacts, 
    Sum([No_of contacts])*100/(select Max(Sum([No_of contacts])) from #t) as Percentage
from #t
Group by HCode 
order by HCode                                                                 Error: Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery.
I am getting above error please find that please give me idea I will appreciate your time. Thankss in advanse

Comment: you can't do a double aggregate, you can achieve this by putting the sum in a CTE and then taking a max from that, but I don't believe that will be the thing you have to do. Or do you need the MAX, this is the highest value in your column. Sum is a sum of all your values in your column.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with the following query:

```
select HCode,Sum(No_of contacts ) as NoOFContacts,(Sum(No_of contacts)*100/(Select Count(*) from #T)) as Percentage
from #T
group by HCode 
order by HCode
```